# Dell Studio 1558 - Missing Drivers after Windows 8 upgrade

Tags: windows-8, drivers, dell-studio

I have upgraded my Dell Studio 1558 laptop to Windows 8 Pro last week (*fresh* upgrade without keeping anything from previous OS). Microsoft has provided almost all essential drivers out of box, but not all. And, Dell is just not thinking about it anymore as the system is old. Now, I am stuck.

- Device Manager is displaying four `Unknown Devices` entry with yellow exclamation sign.
- Windows Action Center is suggesting to install drivers of sensor and card reader.
- I have installed driver of card reader from suggested link given by Action Center, but its not working.
- I am unable to use Bluetooth. It has not been detected by Action Center, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% Tested Solution... I have tested it under Microscope!

1. Do a full Windows Update. One `Unknown Device` entry from Device Manager would vanish.
2. Install [Free Fall Sensor driver](https://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukdhs1/DriverDetails/Product/vostro-3750?driverId=KT7XG&osCode=W864&fileId=3080904014) to remove another `Unknown Device` entry.
   **Note:** The website hasn't listed Dell Studio 1558 as Compatible System, but the sensor model is exactly same.
3. Install [Ricoh Card Reader driver pack 2.15.17.02](http://www.station-drivers.com/page/ricoh.htm) (have 3 drivers) to remove other two `Unknown Device` entries. After system restart, you can test card reader by yourself. It'll work.
   **Note:** Pay attention to the version number and install only this version despite the fact that its not listed under Windows 8.
4. As of now, your device manager will not show any `Unknown Device`, but you know you are unable to use Bluetooth. For that, install [Bluetooth Driver V12.0.0.1600](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=39&m=P8Z77-V%20DELUXE&os=36&ft=27&f_name=Bluetooth_V12001600_Win8.zip#Bluetooth_V12001600_Win8.zip) (again pay attention to version number despite its old) and update it immediately using Windows Update (Windows Update part is important). After restart, you'll be able to use all features of bluetooth.
   **Note:** I am aware that I have given link to Asus's website. Actually, both companies don't manufacture Bluetooth modules by themselves.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Use the installer at http://ftp1.dell.com/folder00865420m/1/Network_Application_VY4F2_WN_12.0_A01.EXE

After installing the driver:

1. Type <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> button, and then type `run`.
2. type `services.msc` and services window will pop up
3. Select the **bluetooth service**, right click it, select **start**, and double click **Bluetooth service**, go to LOG ON tab, click **this account**
4. Click **browse**
5. Click **advanced**
6. Click **find now**
7. Click **local service**
8. Click **ok**

Repeat the same steps in **Bluetooth support service** inside the `service.msc` then restart your laptop, your Bluetooth device should now be functioning.

After restarting the laptop, one Bluetooth icon will appear at your notification bar (right bottom). Right click the **open settings** and tick the **Allow Bluetooth  device to find this computer**.

The Bluetooth device should be working again in Windows 8.